# find all permutations of a string in c++

Tags: c++, string

The following is a code to print all permutations of a given string. The code compiles but does not print anything.

```
using namespace std;

void RecPermute(string, string);

int main() {
    RecPermute("", "abc");
    return 0;
}

void RecPermute(string soFar, string rest) {
    if (rest == " ") {
        cout << soFar << endl;
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<rest.length(); i++) {
            string next = soFar + rest[i];
            string remaining = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i+1);
            RecPermute(next, remaining);
    }
    }
}
```

What needs to be fixed?

Comment: You're starting with "abc" and trimming one character at a time. You'll never get to " ".

Comment: You reinvented this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are so tantalizingly close.  You just want when the empty string is matched as opposed to a space.  You can do this by matching the empty string `""`.

Change

```
if (rest == " ") { ... }
```

to

```
if (rest == "") { ... }
```

and you forgot the length of rest.substr(i+1), it should be (i+1,i-3);

Comment: I'd go for `if (rest.empty())`.

Comment: @greedybuddha I don't get it: What method "opposed to the direct check for empty string"? `isEmpty()` is not a member function of `std::string`. This simply won't compile.

Comment: "So you are so tantalizingly close." Ah yes, those tend to be sometimes the hardest bugs to track down, especially when it's with something to visually similar as "" and " ".

Answer (score 19):

Your approach works (with the correct condition as provided by greedybuddha), but can be achieved much simpler (as suggested by chris).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("abcdefg");
    do
    {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
    while ( std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()) );
}
```

Well what does it do? `std::next_permutation` takes two iterators, one is the beginning of your string, the second is the end, so basically you're saying "consider the whole string". It permutes the string `s` such that after the call, `s` contains the unique permutation that would appear in *lexicographical order* directly after the previous value of `s`. If `s` is the last such permutation (i.e. "gfedcba" for input "abcdefg"), `std::next_permutation` returns `false` and  thus you know you're done.

Since you're not creating any new (temporary) strings with this code, it is not only more readable, but also faster. On my machine, your algorithm takes roughly 5 seconds for "abcdefghij", the one using `std::next_permutation` finishes in less than a second. With another character it becomes worse to 54sec vs. 6.8sec.

Note that if the initial string isn't sorted, this will *not* give the complete list of permutations. But of course there is an easy solution for this: Perform `std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());` before permuting.